# How can I edit an Hdf5 file?

Tags: keras, model, conv-neural-network, hdf5

I have a `keras` CNN  model I am trying to upload to a web app. From my research its simple issue of changing the terminology within the model from `learning_rate` to `lr`, however I can't even open the `hdf5` file anywhere to do this.

I tried to develop a workaround but that didn't work either. The error I got was:

```
Not a location (invalid object ID)
```

The following is the workaround code:

```
image = Image.open(image_path + imageselect)
st.image(image, use_column_width=True)
modfile = 'entire_model.hdf5'
# Importing other python file
import footclas

@st.cache
def foot_class():
    newf = h5py.File(modfile,'r+')
     
    data_p = newf.attrs['training_config']
    data_p = data_p.decode().replace("learning_rate","lr").encode()
    newf.attrs['training_config'] = data_p
    newf.close()
    
    model_1 = load_model(newf)
    return model_1


model_1 = foot_class()
```

Comment: Here you have an example of an XY problem, why do you need to change learning_rate to lr?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to change the value of an attribute at the root level named **'training_config'** from **"learning_rate"** to **"lr"**. Correct? If so, it might be easier to open the file with **HDFView** from The HDF Group and make the change.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  when write the code to upload it to streamlit I always get the error that learning_rate is unidentifiable.  Changing to lr was suggested by the users of this website....the problem is I can't even do that and I really need to get this CNN functioning on the website.

Comment: This  sounds more of a problem because streamlit is using a different keras version (like tf.keras) than the one you are using, so you should fix that, not hack the HDF5 file.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  I've troubleshot as much as I can..I just can't get the model uploaded to streamlit...do you have recommendations?  A Dash or Flask app maybe?